# C# Multiplication Pattern for-loop. Need to figure out how to configure the header of a table of numbers that multiplies each time

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, nested, multiplication

Here is the problem: Write a C# program that uses looping to print the following table of values

```
N  10*N  100*N  1000*N
1  10    100    1000
2  20    200    2000
3  30    300    3000
4  40    400    4000
5  50    500    5000
```

[Update 1] Originally I could not figure out how to get the top left corner (i==0) to be 'N', thank you to the user who pointed out that solution (added in answers below)
What I currently have is this:

```
0  100*N 100*N  100*N
1  10    100    1000
2  20    200    2000
3  30    300    3000
4  40    400    4000
5  50    500    5000
```

[Update 2] Next I had the issue after reorganizing my code to get all the top headers to show 10* N, 100* N, 1000* N. I thought I should use some math equation to do it but instead opted for a literal string. (Maybe there is a better method of doing this?)

Here is my source code:

```
Console.Write("Display the exponent table:\n");
Console.Write("-----------------------------------");
Console.Write("\n\n");

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
   {
       Console.Write(i + "\t");

       for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
          { 
               if (i == 0) Console.Write((i + 10) * 10 + "*N" + "\t");
               else if  (j == 1) Console.Write((i * 10) + "\t");
               else if  (j == 2) Console.Write((i * 100) + "\t");
               else if  (j == 3) Console.Write((i * 1000) + "\t");
               else     Console.Write("\t");
          }

Console.Write("\n");
```

This is an introductory course, so I have not learned more advanced methods of solving this type of problem. It must be solved using basic loops and not more advanced math functions.

Thanks!

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: My apologies, I have not posted to this site much and forgot. It is now added.

Comment: Please do not answer your question in the question itself. Please post your answer as an answer.

Comment: You should restore your question to its original state AND include your original code. If you have another question to ask then ask a new question - don't modify this one. Now Piojo's answer looks very weird.

Comment: @SteamCode666 - I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks, I have posted my solution as an answer and will edit the main question.

Answer (score 1):

When the first case of a loop needs to be specialized somehow, it's usually easiest to check the indices and specialize the code in that case. (Not having seen your code) in this case, that would look something like:

```
if (i == 0 && j == 0)
    cell = "N"; // first cell has a different format
```

It doesn't pay to try being too clever unless the simple solution would make errors or misunderstanding more likely. A comment is good when you need to break a pattern in a way that might be unexpected for someone else reading the code.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used this site much and forgot to add my source code. Your answer worked for correcting my issue with i=0

Answer (score 1):

Here is also a nice solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
    { 
       if(i == 0) Console.Write("N" + (j > 0 ? "*" + Math.Pow(10,j) : "") + "\t");
       else Console.Write(i * Math.Pow(10,j) + "\t");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

In your solution, your inner loop has no big benefit. You could also write just the `Console.Write` without the if checks and without the inner loop. To get from 1 -> 10, 2 -> 100, 3 -> 1000 and so on, you have to calculate 10^j, or in C# `Math.Pow(10, j)`. This solution is easier to extend if you want to add another column.

Comment: It's even nicer if you do this: `for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j *= 10)`. It avoids using `double` maths with the `Math.Pow`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! You are completely right, that is a much cleaner and consolidated solution, however, as far as my course is concerned, only basic looping has been covered so to use Math.Pow would be something not yet taught and outside of the scope of the assignment. Great tip though for similar tasks in the future as I get deeper into C# content learning.

Comment: @SteamCode666 If you can't use `Math.Pow`, there is still Enigmativity's very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with to solve the table of numbers. Thanks, u/piojo for the help!

It is a very basic/literal solution, but the assignment is only intended to use basic looping methods.

If there is an improved or condensed solution other than this, I'd love to see alternative methods.

[SOLUTION]

```
Console.Write("Display the exponent table:\n");
Console.Write("-----------------------------------");
Console.Write("\n\n");

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
   {
       if (i==0) Console.Write("N\t10*N\t100*\t1000*N\t");
       else Console.Write(i + "\t");

       for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
          { 
               if (i == 0) Console.Write(" ");
               else if  (j == 1) Console.Write((i * 10) + "\t");
               else if  (j == 2) Console.Write((i * 100) + "\t");
               else if  (j == 3) Console.Write((i * 1000) + "\t");
               else     Console.Write("\t");
          }

Console.Write("\n");
```